# Trouble logging into macOS

Tags: macos, password, user-account, login

When I left my MacBook Pro for a minute, it closed out, which is normal. But, when I returned, it refused to accept my password to my regular administrator account. So I clicked on Guest User to see if I could log in through there. Now I can’t log into Guest and there is no way I can get back to my regular login. It does not want to accept my password.

How might I troublsehoot this further?

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :) Is there anything else you can tell us that may be related to this? For example, has your MBP been behaving differently in any other ways? Have you recently installed any new software/hardware? Have you tried fully shutting down and rebooting? Also, can you clarify the version of macOS you're using and the exact model of MBP?

Answer (score -1):

I fixed the problem by doing the following steps in this video. Here is the link to the video on youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TjxAgiNqkDM

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.